# Validation Error When Submitting Custom Infopath Form on Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, error, date-time, validation

I recently created a new list for our employees to create new Goals using sharepoint.  I created a content type called “annual performance goals” and created a custom new entry form using infopath to be used when entering new annual performance goals.
My issue is upon Submit, I receive an error message saying that "Field or group: my:CallTime Error: Only date or date and time allowed"
However, the “Date/Time” field (internal SP field name is "CallTime") is a Sharepoint field, I did not add this column to the list.  And it is defaulting to Today() and will not let me edit it to change it to Now() or any other date/time default.  I even tried to make these edits in Infopath and it won’t let me edit the field properties there either.  Attached are some screen shots of what I am talking about.  Please help!
  [image]
[image]

Comment: You can see that I tried to change the default setting to Now() but whenever I do the Quick Publish it reverts right back to Today().  It won't save my change!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! I had to go into infopath->File->Form Options->Advanced->Edit Default Values->and uncheck the field causing the validation error->press OK->republish the form.

Comment: This got fixed my issue.